# How to create htaccess redirect and pass on variables while matching regex?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to create redirects in `.htaccess` for all links that follow a certain url structure. However, the url structure has a variable in it, so I need to pass on the variable into the new url. The variable can be anything (string, number, query, etc), it just needs to be passed on into the new url. For example, `/news-{VARIABLE}-2021` should become `/news-{VARIABLE}-2022`.

Following the `.htaccess` structure with regex, I created this, however the `$` doesn't seem to pass on to the variable `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
Rewrite 301 /news-(.*)$-2021 /news-$1-2022
```

Following some other guides, I also tried to place the `$` at the end of the url, or added a `^` before the first url (with and without the slash `/`). None of these seem to be working however. Could someone explain how I can create these new links with the variable in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot place `$` (end anchor) in the middle of a regex pattern, also don't mix `Rewrite` directive (mod_alias Apache module) with `RewriteEngine` (mod_rewrite Apache module).

You may use:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(news-.+)-2021/?$ /$1-2022 [L,NC,NE,R=301]
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, still not getting forwarded to the 2022 page. When going to /news-awd-2021 it will just give an error 404.

Comment: Fixed it, had to close the browser (Chrome doesn't disable cache for .htaccess or something like that?). Thank you! :)